# How to hide a column set in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a table what combined with 2 tables

```
<div>
        <div>
            <table>
                <colgroup>
                    <col style="width:95px" />
                    <col style="width:95px" />
                    <col style="width:95px" />
                    <col style="width:95px" />
                    <col style="width:95px" />
                </colgroup>
                <tr class="header">
                    <th colspan="2">Header1</th>
                    <th colspan="3">Header2</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>data1</th>
                    <th>data2</th>
                    <th>data3</th>
                    <th>data4</th>
                    <th>data5</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <colgroup>
                <col style="width:95px" />
                <col style="width:95px" />
                <col style="width:95px" />
                <col style="width:95px" />
                <col style="width:95px" />
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <td>data1</td>
                <td>data2</td>
                <td>data3</td>
                <td>data4</td>
                <td>data5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>data1</td>
                <td>data2</td>
                <td>data3</td>
                <td>data4</td>
                <td>data5</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

I want to click one cell on the first header row. Then collapse all the columns in the group except the first column. For example, I click Header2, according to colspan, hide data4 and data5 columns, only show data3 column. Click again show all back.

Also, if I don't use jquery, can I make it only using angular and CSS?

Thanks,
Chen

Comment: can you show what you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `ng-click` and `ng-hide`? A good and relevant example (despite being from the ever-so-awful w3schools) can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_events_hide

Comment: Thanks Joshua. I was thinking about this before. But the tables come from kendo grid. I cannot manually change them for each column or cell. I tried as well with colgroup but it didn't work.